# Upper atmospheric studies in 1930/1940

Tags: atmosphere, balloons, scientific-data

I understand that during 1930/1940s, Baloons were used to gather high altitude data like "pressure" or "temp." I wonder how the instruments "recorded" their data? E.g. The pressure gauge might have noted a pressure of say 5 PSI at an altitude of 22 Km. or the temp. gauge would have noted a temp. of -65 Degree Centigrade etc. But when the balloons came down on earth, they would again show data at sea level.. Hoe did the instruments displayed the data at higher altitudes.

Comment: They used a [Barograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barograph) and a [Thermo-hygrograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermo-hygrograph). But when you ask for pressure depending on altitude, you need another method to determine the height.

Comment: OP is asking about the recording rather than the sensing.

Comment: Relevance of 1930s/1940s balloon experiments to space exploration?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Indirect, but it would have informed early rocket developers' theorizing.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I suppose that depends on how many people VTC it.

Comment: @Organic Marble. I am studying - on my own, out of interest, Space exploration, beginning with "our Journey to the Moon". I am trying to understand "What, How and Why" of many technical achievements. While the "WHYs" are never ending,  every how gives rise to many other "How"s.This question is a part of the quest.

Comment: @Niranjan you've asked many questions here that got good answers. Consider accepting some of those answers! And keep 'em on topic.

Answer (score 3):

I found a little historical info in [this educational weather balloon curriculum](https://www.aiaa.org/docs/default-source/uploadedfiles/education-and-careers/stem-k-12-outreach/educator-academy/space-weather-balloon-module.pdf?sfvrsn=c7150ccf_0).

Very early on, clockwork strip chart recorders were used; these would graph the instrument data on paper during the flight, leaving a permanent record that could be examined when the balloon was retrieved. Radio telemetry came into use starting in 1929, however, so the instruments could be monitored from the ground in real time.

Comment: Borogove, Curriculam site, Strip chart recorders and Radio telemetery is really convincing answer. Thanks.